# Extendscript photoshop version errors

Tags: photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I am using extendscript with Photoshop, but when the version mismatch happens, Photoshop pops up a dialog

[image: Keep layers]

I just want it to keep the layers and proceed. How do I tell Extendscript to do that?

Comment: Can you not do a version check and supress any dialogues that may pop up? Here's a [link](http://forums.adobe.com/message/1914997?tstart=0) that may help

Comment: [This thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/422740) might also prove helpful. It contains a script to capture the message and bypass the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to see the code you're using to understand why the dialog appears.  However, one way around this is to call Photoshop events directly with the `app.executeAction()` call.  The optional third argument is how you want dialogs to be handled; one of the choices you can pass in is `DialogModes.NO` to suppress them.

In order to understand how to create the Photoshop events, you can use the ScriptingListener plugin to see the events generated for various operations.  Here's an [old introduction](http://blogs.adobe.com/crawlspace/2006/05/installing_and_1.html) to it.  You can download the plugin from [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html).